# Erlang OTP based application - architecture ideas

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to write an Erlang application (OTP) that would parse a list of users and then launch workers that will work 24X7 to collect user-data (using three different APIs) from remote servers and store it in ets.

What would be the ideal architecture for this kind of application. Do I launch a bunch of workers - one for each user (assuming small number users)? What will happen if number of users increases very rapidly?

Also, to call different APIs I need to put up a Timer mechanism in the worker process.

Any hint will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawning new process for each user is not a such bad idea. There are http servers that do this for each connection, and they doing quite fine.

First of all cost of creating new process is minimal. And cost of maintaining processes is even smaller.  If one of the has nothing to do, it won't do anything; there is none (almost) runtime overhead from inactive processes, which in the end means that you are doing only the work you have to do (this is in fact the source of Erlang systems reactivity).

Some issue might be memory usage.  Each process has it's own memory stack, and in use-case when they actually do not need to store any internal data, you might be allocating some unnecessary memory.  But this also could be modified (even during runtime), and in most cases such memory will be garbage collected.

Actually I would not worry about such things too soon.  Issues you might encounter might depend on many things, mostly amount of outside data or user activity, and you can not really design this.  Most probably you won't encounter any of them for quite some time. There's no need for premature optimization, especially if you could bind yourself to design that would slow down rest of your development process.  In Erlang, with processes being main source of abstraction you can easily swap this process-per-user with pool-of-workers, and ets with external service.  But only if you really need it.

What's most important is fact that representing "user" as process would be closest to  problem domain. "Users" are independent entities, and deserve separate processes (they have their own state, and they can act or react independent to each other).  It is quite similar to using Objects and Classes in other languages (it is over-simplification, but it should get you going).

Answer (score 1):

If you were writing this in Python or C++ would you worry about how many objects you were creating? Only in extreme cases. In Erlang the same general rule applies for processes. Don't worry about how many you are creating.

As for architecture, the only element that is an architectural issue in your question is whether you should design a fixed worker pool or a 1-for-1 worker pool. The shape of the supervision tree would be an outcome of whichever way you choose.

If you are scraping data your real bottleneck isn't going to be how many processes you have, it will be how many network requests you are able to make per second on each API you are trying to access. You will almost certainly get throttled.

(A few months ago I wrote a test demonstration of a very similar system to what you are describing. The limiting factor was API request limits from providers like fb, YouTube, g+, Yahoo, not number of processes.)

As always with Erlang, write *some system* first, and then benchmark it for real before worrying about performance. You will usually find that performance isn't an issue, and the times that it is you will discover that it is *much* easier to optimize one small part of an existing system than to design an optimized system from scratch. So just go for it and write something that basically does what you want right now, and worry about optimization tweaks after you have something that basically does what you want. After getting some concrete performance data (memory, request latency, etc.) is the time to start thinking about performance.

Your problem will almost certainly be on the API providers' side or your network latency, not congestion within the Erlang VM.